# Декомпиляция apk

Tags: apk, android, компилятор

Есть ли какой-нибудь способ полной декомпиляции?

У меня есть apk tool, который отлично декомпилирует resourse, но без исходников java, и есть show java на телефоне, он отлично декомпилирует в java код, но без ресурсов.

Может быть, есть программа, которая и то, и другое готовым предоставляет?

Comment: apk tool прекрасно декомпилирует java код, но возможно с ошибками в виде место true-1, false-0

Comment: так я там видел только smile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Онлайн](http://www.decompileandroid.com/) декомпилер. На выходе получаете не только `smali`, но и `.java` с ресурсами